# Как добавить option после первого option в select?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как добавить option после первого option в select?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#my_select option:nth-child(1)").after('<option>twotwo</option>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b8acxm9z/

Comment: А можно `option:nth-child(1)` для `find()` использовать?

Comment: Можно - http://jsfiddle.net/b8acxm9z/2/